# How to extract a 'hidden' system font named zt-Mac from Mac OS 9?

Tags: filesystem, font, classic-mac-os

There's a specific font in Mac OS 9 called zt-Mac that I'm dying to use. I'm running Sheepsaver to access OS 9, but want to pull this font out. Unfortunately the font doesn't seem to be within /System/Fonts. [image]

Can anyone help me locate the file for this zt-Mac font?

Comment: Great query - first stop I might make is seeing if this tool can see and get you details… https://www.alanwood.net/unicode/utilities_fonts_mac.html#trueedit or https://web.archive.org/web/20040610232342/http://developer.apple.com/fonts/Tools/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I found the font within the ASCII Fonts suitcase in /System/Fonts, unfortunately when trying to use this font in Ventura Font Book tells me "zt-Mac  9 contains no fonts which can be installed on macOS. Check your selection and try again."

Comment: It's possible that bitmap fonts no longer work in Ventura. You will need some font utility to convert it to TTF. Interestingly, I don't have this font on my SheepShaver installation, and don't recall it from the day. There are of course plenty of simulated pixel fonts available these days.